Get the current active slide of a google slide embedded in an iframe using javascript
I have a embedded google slides into an iframe.
 <iframe
        id="presentation-iframe"
        src={`https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{presentationId}/embed`}
        width="800"
        height="600"
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen
    ></iframe>

I want to know is it possible for me to track the slide change inside an iframe?

So if you see at the bottom there is option to change slides inside iframe. I want to know if somehow I can track the change and can get active slide outside iframe in my application using DOM manipulation. I am using React js
If not possible is there any other way? using Google Slides API? which I can use?

Kindly share a minimal, reproducible example—no sensitive data with your desired output—that the community can use to replicate and see what you'd like to do.

Hi, edited the question
